# Loading Nested XML data in Listview in asp.net & c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, listview, xml-serialization

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Eticket>
    <BookingRef>17313</BookingRef>
    <CompID>HA</CompID>
    <DecimalPreference>2</DecimalPreference>
    <AttachGDSRules>False</AttachGDSRules>
    <FareDetails>
        <BaseFare>1440</BaseFare>
        <Fees>0</Fees>
    </FareDetails>
    <ClientInfo>
        <Client>xyz abc</Client>
        <Address>70 pqrlane</Address>
    </ClientInfo>
</Eticket>
```

**ASPX**

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/temp/temp.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID = "XmlDataSource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div id="ItemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server">
            <span id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server"></span>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="Eticket">
            <asp:Label ID="BookingRef" runat="server" datasrc="#text" Text='<%#XPath("BookingRef") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="CompID" runat="server" Text='<%#XPath("CompID") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="DecimalPreference" runat="server" Text='<%#XPath("DecimalPreference") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="BaseFare" runat="server" Text='<%#XPath("BaseFare") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Client" runat="server" Text='<%#XPath("Client") %>'></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label ID="Address" runat="server" Text='<%#XPath("Address") %>'></asp:Label>                    
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Above data returns me only child values i.e.

Expected output is:

```
17313  HA  2  1440  xyz  abc  70 pqrlane
```

Actual output I am getting is:

```
1440 xyz abc 70 pqrlane
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong.
Hope this information is enough if any more details needed ask for the same.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this, but I guess `XmlDataSource` assumes you have a root element, that contains one or more entities. Your XML-file contains only one entity at the root.

- Either wrap the xml file with another element:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Etickets>
      <Eticket>
          ...
      </Eticket>
  </Etickets>
  ```
- Or specify an XPath-property on the `XmlDataSource`:

  ```
  <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server"
      DataFile="~/temp/temp.xml" XPath="/" />
  ```

Comment: I ask a similar question, would you please check it, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247449/customize-xml-serialize-with-new-tags-and-attributes-and-root